# Customization of Profile Menu element in Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder

I'm trying to customize Profile Menu element in Community Builder.
I created custom lightning component and added it in Builder.
I'd like to move Profile Menu element (with drop down menu) in my new custom component.
But I can't find any solution about this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Profile menu is not a drag and dropable component, it is embedded within the Layout.

If you want to be able to add the profile component in your component, you will have to do so directly in your component code, or Modify the theme layout to include your component in the layout with the profileMenu embedded within it.

you can refer to the following docs:

- [Create Custom Theme Layout Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)
- [Create Custom Search and Profile Menu Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm)

Answer (score 0):

we're using Help Center template and hiding the Log In button didn't work with:

```
.selfServiceUserProfileMenu
{
 display : none;
}
```

which you may find on the Internet, instead we put -

```
.forceCommunityThemeProfileMenu{
 display:none !important;
}
```

(without !important the change was reflected in Community Builder only) and happily get rid of the button :)